# Specific string search

Tags: string, bash, unix, search, grep

I am searching for a simple way to search a very specific string in a document.
For e.g. I want to search only /var in a file, but the search shouldn't output any results containing other sub folders or combination of other words.Generally 'grep -w' helps, but not this time

```
# grep -w /var newfile
/var
/var/tmp
/var/junk
/var iety
/var-nation
# grep -w var newfile
/var
/var/tmp
/var/junk
/var iety
/var-nation
```

But I want to find only '/var' so the result should be something like

```
# {command/script} /var newfile
/var
```

Note: I would really like it if it's a simple command (a few lines od coding will do as well) and it should work in bash on UNIX

Comment: Can you just assume it will be surrounded by spaces e.g. " /var " or assume it will have a new line e.g "/var\n"?

Comment: @Nathan, yes each string would be need to be searched as whole, so "/var" will have new line "/var\n"

Comment: @Genocide, how do I use sed to do it...??? I'm not aware that it can be used for such a 'string' search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^` and `$` to anchor the expression to the beginning and end of each line:

```
grep '^/var$' newfile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply... :) !

Comment: I now have a different problem at hand. What happens if instead of a simple string, I have string with spaces and I've to put that in a variable before performing search.
How do I make it work with a variable with spaces ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with `awk`

```
awk '/^\/var$/' newfile
```

Comment: I now have a different problem at hand. What happens if instead of a simple string, I have string with spaces and I've to put that in a variable before performing search.
How do I make it work with a variable with spaces ?

Comment: `var="some with space"`  Then to search for this, do: `awk '$0~t' t="$var" file`

Comment: I guess, I wasn't clear enough with my question earlier... but thatnks for answering :) !. I want to know how do I use ur awk method for selective searching, if the pattern/variable has space in it ?

Comment: IF you type `awk '/pattern with space/'` it search for whole the line after this pattern that has space.